# Escape dots in Groovy GPath

Tags: json, groovy, rest-assured, gpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using the [RestAssured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) framework in Java, whose documentation contains this [note](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#example-1---json)

> Note that the "json path" syntax uses [Groovy's GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) notation and is not to be confused with Jayway's JsonPath syntax.

I need to validate the following JSON:

```json
"_source": {
    "logSource": {
      "logger.name": "LogbackLogger",
    },
}
```

And the selectors like
`_source.logSource.logger.name` or
`_source.logSource.logger.name[0]` return no result.

I assume this is due to the dot in the `logger.name` property.
If no escaping is done, `logger.name` is interpreted as if `name` was under the `logger`, which is not true.

How do I correctly escape the dot character in the GPath, so that `logger.name` is considered as a single property name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trivial issue.

Just wrap it in between `single quote` i.e., `'logger.name'`
as there is special character.

**Here is complete example :**

```
def string = """{  "_source": {
       "logSource": {
          "logger.name": "LogbackLogger",
      }
    }
}"""

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(string)
println json.'_source'.logSource.'logger.name'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have extrapolated it to the Java case and the solution appeared to be trivial indeed. I only needed to add single quotes: `_source.logSource.'logger.name'[0]`